# Cannot found /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc.sample

Tags: macos, tor, apple-m1

I'm using M1 Macbook.
I installed tor using brew following this [link](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en)
After install I cannot found /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc.sample as in guideline.
I also cannot found /usr/local/etc directory.
Can you help me! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
$ tor -f <path to torrc>
```

It works for me. Hope that it help some one!

Comment: I tried the method you suggested and I got `command not found: tor`

Answer (score 0):

On M1 you will find the torrc file in:
/opt/homebrew/etc/tor